# Ошибка при выборке данных из БД

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite, aiogram, sqlite3

Подключил `Sqlite3`, сделал БД, вылетает ошибка:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

```
import sqlite3
import time

class Database:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def user_exists(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'user_id' = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
            return bool(len(result))

    def add_user(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            return self.connection.execute("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO 'users' ('user_id') VALUES (?)", (user_id,))

    def mute(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            user = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'user_id' = ?", (user_id,)).fetchone()
            return int(user[2]) >= int(time.time())

    def add_mute(self, user_id, mute_time):
        with self.connection:
            return self.connection.execute("UPDATE 'users' SET 'mute_time' = ? WHERE 'user_id' = ?", (int(time.time()) + (mute_time * 60), user_id,))
```

[image: Такая ошибка]

Answer (score 0):

В базе данных просто нет такого пользователя. Я бы рекомендовал делать проверку перед запросом, и по результатам проверки если пользователь отсутствует (select возвращает None), добавлять его в бд а уже потом производить действия.